# Blank Row causing issues with forecasting Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to forecast a line graph and I'm getting the error "To forecast, data cannot have empty values". This didn't make much sense as my x axis is just a date table. However, when I placed it in a table alongside the measure I'm using in the graph, I get the following.I'm guessing the issue comes from the first row being blank. To add more context the Measure1 is a YTD measure with this format:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Transactions'[client_number),
DATESYTD(Calendar[Date]), 'Transaction'[some_filter] = "Y",)
```

Any suggestions?

I've found the same issue here :
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/To-forecast-data-cannot-have-empty-values/m-p/2807393

But the solution didn't seem to work for me.
Thanks!

Edit: Adding photo for clarity.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand. Make what 0? The date? I've edited my question to include the blank row maybe that'll make more sense.

Comment: It does .. So if you are doing exactly the same thing as the question you posted the link .. but sounds like you might need code to convert the EMPTY value to what you need, alas I just deal with database and front ends so I would of just removed the row that has error data instead of writing code to fix the error data, not sure what you do in powerbi for this unfortunately but re-read the link you posted and play around with that, it might be on the right track to convert it for you.

Comment: What I was trying to explain in the previous comment since deleted was in an instance where its expecting an Integer but its being sent an EMPTY value, that would be a text field trying to insert into a number field in other words, so you have to convert the concept of EMPTY into a number that represents empty, in that case 0 works well.  But since its a date, maybe 0/0/0000 might work, but it might also be considered the start of time and cause other issues even if it works, not sure how it would plot.

Comment: I ended up fixing it by adding a condition in my measure that forced dates to not be blank. Calendar_Base[Date] <> BLANK()
Very odd since there weren't any blanks in my data but something with the data model may have added the blank row. 
THank you for the help.

Comment: There you go, filtered away blank values, you got it!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this issue by simple adding Calendar[Date] <> BLANK() in my measure.